# ¿Se puede importar más de 1 componente dentro de una carpeta con una línea de comando?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modulos

Quiero saber si se puede exportar más de un componente con una llamada en React JS tal que así por ejemplo.

Tengo una carpeta llamada Components con 2 componentes, Component1 y Component2.
La forma de llamar los componentes es la siguiente.

```
import Component1 from './Components/Component1';
import Component2 from './Components/Component2';
```

Y quiero saber si se puede hacer algo así por ejemplo:

```
import Component1, Component2 from './Components';
```

Comment: Lo intentaste? Cuál fue el resultado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48269720/16736473)

espero te funcione.

ComponentIndex.js:

```
  let Components = {};

    Components['Component1'] = require('./Component1').default;
    Components['Component2'] = require('./Component2').default;
    Components['Component3'] = require('./Component3').default;

    export default Components
```

main.js :

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Components from './ComponentIndex';

    class Main extends Component {
        render () {
            var type = 'Component1'; // example variable - will change from user input
            const ComponentToRender = Components[type];
            return <ComponentToRender/>
        }
    }

    export default Main
```

Answer (score 0):

En node.js hay una técnica conocida como [Folders as Modules](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules), en donde `node.js` busca por un archivo `package.json` dentro de un directorio; si no lo encuentra, busca por un archivo `index.js`. Esto permite importar el nombre del Directorio como un módulo.

> If there is no package.json file present in the directory, then Node.js will attempt to load an index.js or index.node file out of that directory

Dicho lo anterior, se puede usar la forma [export from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#using_export_from) desde `ReactJS` en combinación con `Folders as Modules`, que es pemitido.

Se tiene una carpeta `Components`, ahí se crea un archivo con nombre `index.js` y se agregan los exports de los componentes requeridos:

```
//Component/index.js
export {Component1} from './Component1';
export {Component2} from './Component2';
```

Luego, para llamarlos en ... `App` por ejemplo:

```
//App.js
import { Component1, Component2 } from './Component'
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

[Preguntas relacionadas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092341/how-do-index-js-files-work-in-react-component-directories/44092481#44092481)

Comment: Si, muchas gracias.